# EmbeddedKafka kafka streams test with SpringBootTest finds two StreamsBuilderFactoryBeans

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

Following the [advice here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/src/reference/asciidoc/testing.adoc#embedded-kafka-annotation), I'm trying to use an embedded Kafka to test my Spring Boot Streams application.

However, simply creating the given configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class StreamsTestConfiguration {

    @Value("${" + EmbeddedKafkaBroker.SPRING_EMBEDDED_KAFKA_BROKERS + "}")
    private String brokerAddresses;

    @Bean(name = KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_CONFIG_BEAN_NAME)
    public KafkaStreamsConfiguration kStreamsConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "testStreams");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, this.brokerAddresses);
        return new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(props);
    }
}
```

and a simple test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedKafka(topics = { "topic" })
public class EmbeddedKafkaTest {
    @Autowired
private MyBean tested;

    @Autowired
    private EmbeddedKafkaBroker kafkaBroker;

    @Test
    public void loaded() {}
}
```

fails to run:

```
Parameter 0 of method kafkaStreamsFactoryBeanConfigurer in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaStreamsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - &defaultKafkaStreamsBuilder: defined by method 'defaultKafkaStreamsBuilder' in class path resource [org/springframework/kafka/annotation/KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.class]
    - &stream-builder-process: defined in null
 [...]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaStreamsFactoryBeanConfigurer' defined in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaStreamsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'kafkaStreamsFactoryBeanConfigurer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.config.StreamsBuilderFactoryBean' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: &defaultKafkaStreamsBuilder,&stream-builder-process
```

If I remove the `@SpringBootTest` from the test class, the problem disappears, but then the actual bean under test fails to autowire.

I don't define a `StreamBuilderFactoryBean` myself, where are they coming from?

Also: is this this setup even worthwhile for testing a stream that is used to feed a `KTable` that is later being queried? It's not like I can "use a different topic for each test" since the stream will always use the same topic. My hope is that I can get around that with proper test case design, or am I going to hit a wall I can't see yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to you stack trace, you also use Spring Cloud Stream with Kafka Streams Binder. Please, add an appropriate tag.

Consider to remove an explicit `@EnableKafkaStreams` since Binder is going to take care about infrastructure for you.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I did that, but also had to add a `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers` entry or some listener wouldn't find their Kafka (trying to fall back to `localhost:9092` rather than using the embedded one).